# HTTP get request in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am totally new to VB as I have just started to learn it.

I have already created a user form with an input text box and a button. I want to be able to scan a barcode and implement it into this link: `http://openean.kaufkauf.net/?ean=\[ean\]&cmd=query&queryid=200000000` replacing `[ean]` with the numbers from the barcode.

Afterwards make a HTTP GET request and having the result pop up in a message box. I do not know how to take the value of the text box, paste it into the link and make the request.

Comment: If you haven't coded anything yet, you'll probably want to learn the basics of the language before attempting something like this.  Questions have a better chance of getting answered here if you show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your text box is named `TextBox1`, try:

```
Dim request As String = String.Format("http://openean.kaufkauf.net/?ean={0}&cmd=query&queryid=200000000", TextBox1.Text)
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString(request)

MessageBox.Show(result)
```

Note that the above code will wait for the result from the server before allowing the user to interact with the application again, but it's enough to get you started.